# Derived Scala case class with same member variables as base

Tags: scala

Is there a nicer way of doing this?

```
scala> case class A(x : Int)
defined class A

scala> case class B(override val x : Int, y : Int) extends A(x)
defined class B
```

I'm extending A with B and adding an extra member variable. It would be nice not to have to write `override val` before the x.

Comment: This example looks like I'm being a bit fussy but if the base class has a lot of member variables all the `override def`s start to add up.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, case classes work like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would strongly advise not to inherit from a case class. It has surprising effects on equals and hashCode, and has been deprecated in Scala 2.8.

Instead, define `x` in a trait or an abstract class.

```
scala> trait A { val x: Int }
defined trait A

scala> case class B(val x: Int, y: Int) extends A
defined class B
```

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3289

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1582

Comment: On 2.8 I see nothing surprizing regarding equals/hashCode. All required properties of equals are maintained in the most intuitive way. (Instances with runtime type of `case class A` are never equal to instances of `case class B`, regardless if there is inheritance involved).

Comment: To be precise, case classes should not inherit from other case classes. It's OK (and quite common) to let a normal class inherit from a case class.

Comment: So that means if you write case classes you are effectively sealing those classes. It's a side-effect I wouldn't have expected but I'll be careful of in future.