# Matching sub-classes of case classes in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

Why does this fail to compile (or work?):

```
  case class A(x: Int)
  class B extends A(5)

  (new B) match {
    case A(_) => println("found A")
    case _ => println("something else happened?")
  }
```

The compiler error is:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;  found   : blevins.example.App.A  required: blevins.example.App.B
```

Note that this compiles and runs as expected:

```
  (new B) match {
    case a: A => println("found A")
    case _ => println("something else happened?")
  }
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

Just for reference, this compiles and runs fine:

```
  class A(val x: Int)
  object A {
    def unapply(a: A) = Some(a.x)
  }
  class B extends A(5)

  (new B) match {
    case A(i) => println("found A")
    case _ => println("something else happened?")
  }
```

Comment: I believe this to be one of the bugs presently open on pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

This works, at least in 2.8:

```
scala>   case class A(x: Int)                           
defined class A

scala>   class B extends A(5)                           
defined class B

scala>   (new B: A) match {                             
     |     case A(_) => println("found A")              
     |     case _ => println("something else happened?")
     |   }                                              
found A
```

I haven't found the a pointer to the particular bug that causes the original problem, but ignore the warnings about case class inheritance at your own peril.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Do you know of an official source for the warnings about class inheritance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058827/derived-scala-case-class-with-same-member-variables-as-base/2059203#2059203

Comment: Am I reading correctly that the deprecation is limited to case classes extending other case classes?  My unexpected behavior above is a plain-jane class extending a case class.

Comment: That's correct, the deprecation is limited to case classes (and objects) extending other case classes.